# Admob ads aren't showing after updating API to 33

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

Actually, it worked well both in internal test and directly transferring Apk into my phone.

Google console keep warning me to update the target API version to 33, I made some changes as following description.

Gladly, no warning pops up after uploading app bundle, but another problem has occurred.

I tried to change advertising ID (ca-up... blah blah) into sample ID which is displayed at beginner guide, but this was not the problem.

Comment: Any errors you get on logcat for admob? (When running on Android)